# Vegetarian Mini-Pill (Progestin Only Birth Control)

Tags: lacto-ovo-vegetarianism, is-it-vegetarian, lacto-vegetarianism, medicine

Does anyone know if any of the "mini pill" brands of [progestin-only birth control](https://youngwomenshealth.org/2014/07/08/progestin-only-oral-contraceptives/) are vegetarian? I need progestin only options for medical reasons (options which contain estrogen are not options due to a medical condition, and I'm looking for PMS-controlling options, so I need hormonal birth control, not condoms or something).

I'm a lacto ovo vegetarian, so lactose is okay, and I've made my peace with the fact that animal testing may have been involved at some point, but anything non-vegetarian like bovine-sourced magnesium stearate is right out.

I just contacted the Camila brand and was told that the source of magnesium stearate in their pills is bovine, so unfortunately, the brand I was originally recommended was out. Rather than going down the list of manufacturers, I was hoping someone here might know of a suitable brand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just got a call from a very nice woman at Northstar pharmaceuticals who informed me that both Deblitane and Sharobel contain "no animal derived ingredients, including shellfish". While she could not guarantee cross contamination did not occur, I'd say that's good enough for me.

Incassia was also confirmed to be vegetarian; its magnesium stearate is from plant and mineral sources, and its stearic acid is derived from palm oil sourced from Malaysia.

I do also have inquiries open with a few other manufacturers, and will update this answer with any others that come back as being suitable for vegetarians.

(As a note, I'm not sure this means it is vegan... I specified "lacto ovo vegetarian" and I suspect it may contain milk products and she was just using slightly sloppy with her language. To my knowledge there is no vegan birth control pill available in any form)